# CSS for mobile font-size

Tags: css, mobile

When designing a mobile site, what's the best way to declare font-size? Currently although I'm using viewport, my text which should be only 1 line, breaks into 2 lines. Should I declare my font-size using px, em, % or (small, large, etc)? Cheers :)

Comment: It doesn't matter... Use what you like. If you need a more generic approach try searching for 'fluid font javascript', there are many javascript libraries to make text always fit one line. For example: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pixel or em is fine, but if you want your fonts to look the same in the mobile view, you should add

`-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`

that'll keep the size but it will affect the readability.

**Syntax**

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none | auto | <percentage>;
```